# Is there any way we can get workflow step trigger types in the followed step to put a condition? [github actions]

Tags: github-actions

I on:
pull_request:
types: [opened, synchronize,reopened,edited]

jobs:
pull_request:
steps:
- name: STEP 1
//
- name: STEP 2
//
- name: STEP 3
//
THE WORKFLOW IS TRIGGERED WHEN THE WORKFLOW TYPES ARE DEFINED AS "opened, synchronize, reopened, edited"

I WANTED TO SKIP SOME STEP BASED ON THE TYPES THAT TRIGGER THE WORKFLOW
BASICALLY ADDING A CONDITION WHETHER TO RUN STEP 1 IF TYPE = synchronize  AND RUN STEP 2 IF TYPE IS OPENED
LET ME KNOW IF IT IS POSSIBLE OR ANY WORKAROUND WE CAN IMPLEMENT

Answer (score 0):

You can use `github.event_name` which gives you `The name of the event that triggered the workflow run`

and then use condition like

```
if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'opened'
```

Comment: Thanks ! needed `github.event.action == 'opened'`

Comment: Can you consider marking my reply as answer if it solves your issue?